# Where do I specify ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData for NSURLSession in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, nsurlsession

I have an app that makes an API call every 5 seconds using NSURLSession and [p2-oauth2](https://github.com/p2/OAuth2). I'm running into an issue of it returning cached data instead of the updated information from the API. I read [this post](http://nshipster.com/nsurlcache/) by Matt Thompson where he describes the different cache policies, the one I think I need to use is `ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`. I think it's suppose to be put in the AppDelegate DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions functions. But, the problem I'm having is I don't know where or how to specify it. I haven't found any Swift solutions. Can anyone tell me what my function should say?

If it's helpful, here is my API request:

```
    let urlPath = "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/\(uberRequestId)"
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    guard let endpoint = NSURL(string: urlPath) else { print("Error creating endpoint");return }
    let request = appDelegate.oauth.request(forURL: NSURL(string:urlPath)!)
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    //get response from Uber and iterate through to find Uber Product ID.
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            guard let dat = data else { throw JSONError.NoData }

            let result = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dat, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)

            print(result)

            //set status
            status = result["status"] as! String

            print("found status...returning it back -> \(status)")
            completion(status: "\(status)")

        } catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
            print("ERROR NEEDS TO BE HANDLED.")
        } catch {
            print(error)
            print("ERROR NEEDS TO BE HANDLED.")
        }
    }.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the OAuth API returns a mutable request, you can set its **cachePolicy** property to NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData.

Comment: where do I add ReloadIgnoringLocaclCacheData to my request? Or do I add it to my appDelegate?

Comment: I found in the Oauth files the request. However I tried changing `NSURLRequestCachePolicy` to `ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` but it gives me an error, undeclared type "ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData".  Here is the full public function that contains the cachePolicy:

`convenience init(URL: NSURL!, oauth: OAuth2, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: NSTimeInterval) {
  self.init(URL: URL, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: timeoutInterval)
  self.sign(oauth)
 }`

Comment: I assume you mean that you tried changing cachePolicy.  NSURLRequestCachePolicy is a data type (an enumeration, specifically), not a parameter name.  With that said, if ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData doesn't work, try NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData (the full C symbol name).  It is possible that the docs are wrong.

Comment: Apparently, it is NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData.  Blech, what a horrible syntax.  :-)

Comment: Yea...not good, but it's working well now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @dgatwood. I tried adding my code that worked to your answer, but the mods rejected it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final request that properly sets the cache policy. I added one line with `ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`.

```
let urlPath = "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/\(uberRequestId)"
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let request = appDelegate.oauth.request(forURL: NSURL(string:urlPath)!)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

//added this line to set cache policy
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    (
    let data, let response, let error) in

    guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
        print("error")
        return
    }

    let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(dataString)

}

task.resume()
```